# "That is what I told her." "That was what I told her." Meanings are different?

Tags: meaning

> (1)That is what I told her.
>
> (2)That was what I told her.

Are their meanings different??

And I found that some people on the net(not english native speakers) said using "that" with past tense, using "this" with present tense. For example

> (3)that was what I told her.
>
> (4)this is what I told her.

Is that true?? If that is correct, as an English learner, I still can not tell the difference of their meanings by myself, so I think if someone could answer and explain a little bit about these qusetions, it will be great, helpful and awesome!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It will help us help you if you can identify what the dictionary definitions were and why you are still confused. I also encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: And please use I  not i when you refer to yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* sort of an element of tense to set those two apart, but it is subtle. When you use

> This is what I told her.

you haven't yet said what you told her, but are about to. On the other hand, when you use

> That is what I told her.

you have already told the listener what you said. So if what you said to her was *My car is the blue one*, you would tell the story either this way:

> "My car is the blue one." That is what I told her.

or this way:

> This is what I told her: "My car is the blue one."

So the tense involved is in the order of the information you are giving, not in the content of your information. If it makes more sense in comparison to your language, you can think of *this* as a new information marker, while *that* is used for information that has already been discussed.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I am glad that you helped me. Your answer is really useful and easy to understand.
But i am still confused about the tense just like what i mentioned at the beginning, "That is what..." and "That was what...". Would you mind helping me out again?? Thanks!

Comment: Well, telling her happened in the past, so you *can* use *was*. However, it is also true that what you told her is *still* what you told her, so you can also use *is*. The only thing that is definitively in the past, always, is *told*, since the telling happened in the past.